# Pass a value via CloudPageURL that will populate a SmartCapture hidden field

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, smart-capture

I have a SmartCapture form that populates a DE that has three attributes:

- SubscriberKey
- Comment
- Score

SubscriberKey and Score are both hidden values, and I want to populate them based on the link that the person clicks to get there.  I am sending an email with 3 different links, where the only difference is the value of "Score".
Using standard CloudPageURL() makes it easy to pass in SubscriberKey and retrieve it in the form as %%_subscriberkey%%.  My challenge is trying to figure out how to pass in a specific value for "Score" for each of the URLs.
I'm assuming I can still use CloudPageURL() functionality, but am not sure what the syntax should be since I am passing in a value and not a variable

- href="%%=CloudPagesURL(453,'Score','good')
- href="%%=CloudPagesURL(453,'Score','medium')
- href="%%=CloudPagesURL(453,'Score','bad')

a different attempt

- href="%%=CloudPagesURL(453,'Score',@good)

None of these seem to work - i.e. the resulting encrypted URL either gives an error, or just a blank page.

My hope is that once I get the URL working, I can retrieve the score as a hidden value in the form:
[image: Reference hidden fields]

Answer (score 0):

use this one in form set @score=QUERYPARAMETER('score')  after the give like this

```
 <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(453, 'score','good')=%%>Click1</a>
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(453, 'score','medium')=%%>Click2</a>
 <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(453, 'score','bad')=%%>Click3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a query parameter to the hidden field of a Smart Capture form by entering the following into the Hidden Attribute text field in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud editor. In this case 'uuid' is the name of the parameter specified in the URL

%%=v(QUERYPARAMETER('uuid'))=%%